# Zoom out in rqt/plot

Tags: rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I am using hydro under ubuntu 12.04LTS and it turns out I can find no way to zoom out the time in the rqt/plot window. You can zoom in using the *Zoom to rectangle* tool, but I can find no way to zoom out. Moreover the zoom is reset when enabling autoscroll, hence I could find no way to change the zoom on the time axis (x axis) when autoscrolling.

Any idea if zooming out in time is possible at all in the rqt/plot view?

Thanks,

Antoine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187036/zoom-out-in-rqt/plot/) by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2014-07-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like it is possible if you disable auto-scroll. Click on the cross-shaped icon with arrows labelled "pan axes with left mouse, zoom with right". Then go to the graph itself, hold down the right mouse button, and move the mouse to the left.  That should zoom out your time axis, if I understand correctly what you are trying to do.

---

Originally posted by [vkulikauskas](https://answers.ros.org/users/18827/vkulikauskas/) with karma: 126 on 2014-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on 2017-03-13**:
With the "Zoom to rectangle tool" in Kinetic you can also right click and draw a rectangle to zoom out, even with autoscroll on.